# ADD / REMOVE inputs dynamically ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am new on React and these state values are going to kill me! What I am trying to do is add `input` with `select options`and each `select option`is connected to its `input`and when I delete on of them I want to delete them together but this is not happening.

When I delete any one, only the last line is deleted and the `select option` does not stick with the same `input`.

This is my code:

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  class SocialMedia extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      SocialData: [],
      socialArray: [
        {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Website",
        "regex": "(https|http):\\/\\/(www\\.)*"
        },
        {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Last.fm",
        "regex": "(https|http):\\/\\/www\\.(lastfm\\.com|last\\.fm\\/|lastfm\\.ch).*"
        },
        {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Facebook",
        "regex": "https:\\/\\/www\\.facebook\\.com\\/.*"
        },
        {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Twitter",
        "regex": "(https|http):\\/\\/(twitter\\.com).*"
        },
        {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Instagram",
        "regex": "https:\\/\\/(instagr\\.am\\/.*|instagram\\.com\\/.*)"
        },
        {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "YouTube Channel",
        "regex": "((http|https):\\/\\/|)(www\\.)?youtube\\.com\\/(channel\\/|user\\/)[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}"
        },
        {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "YouTube Video",
        "regex": "^.*(youtu.be\\/|v\\/|e\\/|u\\/\\w+\\/|embed\\/|v=)([^#\\&\\?]*).*"
        },
        {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Spotify",
        "regex": "spotify\\:+"
        }
        ]
    };
    this.handleAddSocial = this.handleAddSocial.bind(this);
    this.handleInputVlaueChange = this.handleInputVlaueChange.bind(this);
    this.handleRemoveSocial = this.handleRemoveSocial.bind(this);
    this.selectHandler = this.selectHandler.bind(this);
  }

  handleAddSocial () {
    let array = this.state.SocialData;
    array.push({ id: array.length+1 , socialname: '' })
    this.setState({ SocialData: array})
  }

  handleInputVlaueChange (e ) {
    console.log(e.target.value)
  }

  handleRemoveSocial (e) {
    let someArray = this.state.SocialData;
    someArray.splice( someArray.indexOf(e), 1);
    this.setState({ SocialData: someArray })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <button  
          className="newFlyerButton btn mb-4"
          type="button" 
          onClick={this.handleAddSocial}
        >
          <span>
            <img src={plus} alt="plus" className="newFlyerPlus"/>
            <span className="buttonText">ADD NEW</span>
          </span>
        </button>

        <table className="table mt-3 bordered table-hover  white-table addNewSocial">
          <tbody>
            {this.state.SocialData.map((Social, idx) => (
              <tr key={idx} className="row Social">
                <td className="col-6 socialInput">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder={`Add New # ${idx+1}`}
                    value={Social.name}
                    onChange={this.handleInputVlaueChange}
                  />
                </td>
                <td className="col-4 socialSelector">
                  <select defaultValue="SelectOption">
                    <option value="SelectOption" disabled >Select your option</option>
                    { this.state.socialArray.map(socidata =>
                      <option 
                        value={socidata.name} 
                        data={socidata} 
                        key={socidata.id}
                      >
                        {socidata.name}
                      </option>
                    )}
                  </select>
                </td>
                <td className="col-2 closingLink">
                  <i className="fas fa-fw fa-times" onClick={ () => this.handleRemoveSocial(idx) }></i>
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default SocialMedia;
```

How can I connect each social media selection with the same input in line?

Comment: Where is declared selectHandler  ?

Comment: Please add your current result and expected result so we understand better. Also, a sandbox example is also very useful for anyone to help you a bit faster ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understood, you want to remove the correct input based on the index you send to `handleRemoveSocial` and also keep track of the social name of each input, right?

To solve your problem, these are some changes you should make:

1. Since `handleRemoveSocial` already receives `idx`, you don't need to use `indexOf`, so: `someArray.splice( someArray.indexOf(e), 1);` becomes `someArray.splice(e, 1);`
2. You need to keep track of `<select>` changes and change your state accordingly, for that, you should have a method like `handleSocialNameChange` that sets a new state with the social name.
3. Use the `socialname` field inside each object of `this.state.SocialData` to render the selected option on `<select>`.

Code with the modifications:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SocialMedia extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      SocialData: [],
      socialArray: [
        {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Website",
        "regex": "(https|http):\\/\\/(www\\.)*"
        },
        {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Last.fm",
        "regex": "(https|http):\\/\\/www\\.(lastfm\\.com|last\\.fm\\/|lastfm\\.ch).*"
        },
        {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Facebook",
        "regex": "https:\\/\\/www\\.facebook\\.com\\/.*"
        },
        {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Twitter",
        "regex": "(https|http):\\/\\/(twitter\\.com).*"
        },
        {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Instagram",
        "regex": "https:\\/\\/(instagr\\.am\\/.*|instagram\\.com\\/.*)"
        },
        {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "YouTube Channel",
        "regex": "((http|https):\\/\\/|)(www\\.)?youtube\\.com\\/(channel\\/|user\\/)[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}"
        },
        {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "YouTube Video",
        "regex": "^.*(youtu.be\\/|v\\/|e\\/|u\\/\\w+\\/|embed\\/|v=)([^#\\&\\?]*).*"
        },
        {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Spotify",
        "regex": "spotify\\:+"
        }
        ]
    };
    this.handleAddSocial = this.handleAddSocial.bind(this);
    this.handleInputValueChange = this.handleInputValueChange.bind(this);
    this.handleRemoveSocial = this.handleRemoveSocial.bind(this);
    this.handleSocialNameChange = this.handleSocialNameChange.bind(this);
    this.selectHandler = this.selectHandler.bind(this);
  }

  handleAddSocial () {
    let array = this.state.SocialData;
    array.push({ id: array.length+1 , socialname: '' })
    this.setState({ SocialData: array})
  }

  handleInputValueChange(e, idx) {
    let nextSocialData = this.state.SocialData.slice();
    nextSocialData[idx].name = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ SocialData: nextSocialData });
  }

  handleSocialNameChange(socialName, idx) {
    let nextSocialData = this.state.SocialData.slice();
    nextSocialData[idx].socialname = socialName;
    this.setState({ SocialData: nextSocialData });
  }

  handleRemoveSocial(idx) {
    let someArray = this.state.SocialData;
    someArray.splice(idx, 1);
    this.setState({ SocialData: someArray });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <button  
          className="newFlyerButton btn mb-4"
          type="button" 
          onClick={this.handleAddSocial}
        >
          <span>
            <img src={plus} alt="plus" className="newFlyerPlus"/>
            <span className="buttonText">ADD NEW</span>
          </span>
        </button>

        <table className="table mt-3 bordered table-hover  white-table addNewSocial">
          <tbody>
            {this.state.SocialData.map((Social, idx) => (
              <tr key={idx} className="row Social">
                <td className="col-6 socialInput">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder={`Add New # ${idx+1}`}
                    value={Social.name}
                    onChange={this.handleInputValueChange}
                  />
                </td>
                <td className="col-4 socialSelector">
                  <select
                    onChange={e => {
                      this.handleSocialNameChange(e.target.value, idx);
                    }}
                    value={Social.socialname || "SelectOption"}
                  >
                    <option value="SelectOption" disabled >Select your option</option>
                    { this.state.socialArray.map(socidata =>
                      <option 
                        value={socidata.name} 
                        data={socidata} 
                        key={socidata.id}
                      >
                        {socidata.name}
                      </option>
                    )}
                  </select>
                </td>
                <td className="col-2 closingLink">
                  <i className="fas fa-fw fa-times" onClick={ () => this.handleRemoveSocial(idx) }></i>
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default SocialMedia;
```

I've also created a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/2w5xj8pmzp) with these changes and also made some modifications so the code could run (like removing `selectHandler` which isn't defined).

I hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you - Thiago it is working for the selection option but if you have 3 inputs and fill the input with anything , you will see that when you delete the second line the last value line will be deleted not the second one.

Comment: Edited the answer and the sandbox to implement `handleInputValueChange`. This makes the input controlled via `Social.name`

Comment: Working perfectly, Thank you so much Thiago you made my day God bless you

Comment: @Thiago Murakami Just 1 question. How can we clear the input field when we change the value from dropdown.

Comment: Please someone help me clearing the input fields when we change the value of dropdown